# Importing data with SRID 4269 to GEOGRAPHY type of PostGIS?

Tags: postgis-2.0

In PostGIS, we are importing various US census bureau shapefiles (with SRID = 4269) using **shp2pgsql** loader.  I have medium-sized database with several tables containing fields of type geography (lat/lon points, polygons, multipolygons, etc) that span locations across the US on which we do various distance calculations, “within” polygon, etc type of geographic functions as well as display data using Google Maps Api.  We currently have no geometry type fields (only SRID used in database is 4326 via geography type).

Because they cover a fairly large area and to keep things simple and consistent (avoid projection details etc), I would like to store the census shapes (ie boundaries for states, metros, counties,block groups..) in geography data type instead of geometry  as well (unless there is a reason NOT to do this or someone can explain why we should store as geometry instead).

If I use shp2pgsql loader with –G option to create a MULTIPOLYGON geography field for these boundaries (and thus use a 4326 SRID) does the loader “convert” the data from a 4269 projection to 4326?

Is a conversion really necessary?

Do I need to first load into temp table with geometry type then perform update to transform/cast into geography type and then store that result?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to use geography data type... well... you can still store geographic coordinates (lat lng) in a geometry column. Geographic coordinates are not exclusive to geography type in postgis. The difference is how certain functions behave, like distance measurements, etc... Read more here:

http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.5/ch04.html#PostGIS_Geography

Bottomline, if you want precise calculations on geographic coordinates, use geography type, otherwise use geometry type. Note that by using geography type you will loose some of the functions which are not implemented for that type. Another note: because in a small area, a sphere (which is the base of calculations of geography type) is similar to a plane, so the difference between the results of measurements using either data type wont be big, but they of course increase with size of your spatial objects as a plane doesn't represent the surface of a sphere as the area of interest grows

About the data import, there are 2 options:

1. Import data as is... then reproject in the database (add a column with geography type, and use builtin postgis functions to reproject through a query)
2. Use shp2pgsql with -s from_srid:to_srid check this link http://www.bostongis.com/pgsql2shp_shp2pgsql_quickguide_20.bqg

Answer (score 1):

I believe PostGIS geography data type handles only 4326 SRID at the moment (it requires lon/lat data in WGS84), so your options:

1.Convert the 4269 SRID data to 4326 projection yourself *before* loading it to PostGIS using shp2pgsql *with* the -G option to get the final 4326 Geography data,

2.or load the 4269 SRID data *without* the -G option,

`shp2pgsql -r 4269 -s 4326 schema.table | psql -h host -d database -U user`

and change the geometry data into geography within PostGIS using `Geography(ST_Transform(geometry,srid))` function. There's an example on how to do this in http://workshops.opengeo.org/postgis-intro/geography.html

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

shp2pgsql can reproject (provided you have proj installed)

first  you create the sql dump:

```
shp2pgsql -s 4269:4326 -g geom -I  <schema>.<dbname> > dump.sql
```

then you load it at your postgis db:

```
psql -f dump.sql
```

you're done

If you already have the data in postgis a better way is to create a new geom collumn  with another SRID:

```
-- create the column:
ALTER TABLE <schema>.<tablename> ADD COLUMN geom_4326 geometry;
-- Populate it:
UPDATE <schema>.<tablename> set geom_4326 = st_translate(geom,4326);
```

Answer (score 0):

*PostGIS in Action* (2015), p.87, discusses switches on `shp2pgsql`:

> -g—Sets the name of the geometry or geography column in the table created by shp2pgsql. The default is geom for geometry and geog for
>   geography.
>
> -s—Specifies the spatial reference system (SRS) of the source data; you should always include this switch. Even if a projection is
>   present, PostGIS still can’t make an accurate determination of the
>   SRID. Since PostGIS 2.0, you can also indicate the SRID of the
>   destination, effectively letting you perform a transformation dur-ing
>   the load. The format of the switch is -s srid_from:srid_to. For
>   example,
>   -s 26986:4326 means that the source data is in Massachusetts State Plane
>
> -G—Loads to the geography type instead of the geometry type; the default is the geometry type. Shp2pgsql will only honor this switch if
>   your data is in WGS 84 lon/lat (SRID 4326). You can, however,
>   transform during the load to WGS 84 with the -s switch, as in -G -s
>   26986:4326.